# Timber+Twig: Check template type

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have a header.twig that renders universally throughout a website.

For archive pages, I'd like to make a small change within the header.

I could do this the regular way by making a new Twig file (e.g. header-archive.twig) or avoid making another file, I could pass/check a custom variable in the existing header.twig...

or

**QUESTION:** Is there an official *Twig-only* way to check template-type (archive vs single vs page, etc) in a Timber website?

For example, the equivalent of getting [{{ post.type }}](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#type), but for template type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twig-only way to use [conditionals](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) is to use [`fn()` or `function()`](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/) to call the appropriate function.

```
{% if fn('is_archive') %}
{% endif %}

{% if fn('is_post_type_archive', 'my_post_type') %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Great answer, what about if its not the post type of archive? How would the syntax read? `{% if fn('isnot_archive') %}`  is not working for me?

Comment: @ShrockCo You can use `{% if not fn('is_archive') %}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works great but wondering if I can exclude the front or the home page (set in wordpress) in the same function as well? This does not seem to be working `{% if not fn('is_archive', 'is_home') %}`

Comment: @ShrockCo You would use the [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) function for that. In Twig, that would mean `{% if not fn('is_front_page') %}`. There’s also [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/), which returns true on your posts archive. If you display your post archive on the front page, then you could also use `is_home()`.

Comment: So they must be in separate functions then?

Comment: @ShrockCo What do you mean with that? Depending on what you have set in Settings → Reading in your WordPress Administration you will either have to use `is_front_page()` or `is_home()` when you use `{% if not fn('…') %}` in Twig.

Comment: What I meant was `{% if not fn('is_archive', 'is_home') %}` does not seem to work? Seems I have to use these 2 functions separately. `{% if not fn('is_single') %}` and 
`{% if not fn('is_home') %}`

Comment: @ShrockCo Okay, now I get it. When you use `fn('is_archive', 'is_home')`, that whould translate to `is_archive('is_home')` in PHP, which is not what you want, as you realized yourself. If you want to use multiple checks in one `if`, you can use `and` or `or`, like this: `{% if not fn('is_single') and not fn('is_front_page') %}`. You may find more information for this in the [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/if.html).

Comment: and that works - Thanks so much for the example and clarification, I sure appreciate it!!